# Tomcat (Development) fails to start after adding UTF8 support in application and setting needed JVM options

Tags: tomcat, configuration, jvm, myfaces

I am failing to get Tomcat 7.0.27 to start. This is not a ServerFault question as this is my development server. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and my application ran no errors prior to adding a Filter to my application. This filter is not the cause of the issue as I am using it successfully on my production server where IDEA  compiles, packages and runs it without problems that inhibit me from developing. 
What's my issue then?

I noticed a minor error that bubbled from Tomcat. It doesn't log into log files but reads:

```
Unable to use direct char[] access of java.lang.String
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: count
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1899)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.StringCharArrayAccessor.<clinit>(StringCharArrayAccessor.java:63)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.StreamCharBuffer.readAsString(StreamCharBuffer.java:605)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.StreamCharBuffer.toString(StreamCharBuffer.java:631)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseWriterImpl.writeScriptContent(HtmlResponseWriterImpl.java:484)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseWriterImpl.endElement(HtmlResponseWriterImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EndElementInstruction.write(EndElementInstruction.java:38)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:46)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:505)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:764)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1900)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.buhaugane.web.filters.CharsFilter.doFilter(CharsFilter.java:38)
    at ...
```

I suspect from looking online that I need to add some params for VM to tomcat `catalina.bat` Specifically one that tells it to reqquest the JVM to run with utf-8(I am using Windows 8 by the way) I can rule The Filter I use as the sole cause for this irritation as removeing it fixes everything The only thing the filter does is modify the HTTP request with a UTF-8 value loaded when it is initialized by the container: `request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);` and when I tried adding the following to the file Tomcat would not start, complaining that the variable I gave contains invalid values. It is written exactly as is. I would like assistance to resolve this issue so that my development environment mimics production. Any assistance is appreciated.

The variable I use is configured:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% ^
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager ^
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties ^
-Xms128m -Xmx256m ^
=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

In short, I would like to eliminate all errors that could cause future issues and I believe that telling Tomcat to use UTF-8 JVM will assist me. Is there a visible error with the value I posted?

Comment: What is an _equals_ sign (=) doing in the last row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your **myfaces** version. I had the same issue and could fix it by upgrading to the latest myfaces version. In particular I updated the following two jar files:

- myfaces-api.jar (to version 2.1.10, I was using 2.1.6 before)
- myfaces-impl.jar (to version 2.1.10, I was using 2.1.6 before)

The error happend here: `org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.StringCharArrayAccessor.<clinit>(StringCharArrayAccessor.java:63)`

This was working fine with Java 6 but isn't with Java 7. I guess the `count` field has been removed from the Java 7 implementation. Fortunatly the myfaces team already fixed that issue. Just update your jar-files (see above).

Answer (score 2):

The error you have is just a debug information : https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/util/StringCharArrayAccessor.java

Regarding the code, it tries to detect if the String class has been wrapped and have some additional methods. If yes, grails will use an optimized version, otherwise the fallback.

So you can probably ignore this error.

HIH

Comment: Thank you. I also managed to determine that it may be a jk7 issue related to Tomcat, but the forum I rsd this on was Ubuntu and may be specfically related to an Ubuntu packaged JDK, so did not post here with regards to that.